# Berndeutsches Sprichwort – Bedeutung?

Tags: meaning, proverb, swiss-german

In einem berndeutschen Song habe ich folgendes Sprichwort gehört:

> We nid wosch das d’Miuch suur wird de lasch se gschider i der Chue.

Die Übersetzung lautet etwa:

> Wenn du nicht willst, dass die Milch sauer wird, dann lässt du sie besser in der Kuh.

Was will dieses Sprichwort ausdrücken?

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass die Übersetzung in Hochdeutsch richtig ist? Ich kann zwar kein Schweizerdeutsch, aber mit meinem schwäbischen Sprachgefühl hätte ich "wosch" als "weißt" und nicht als "willst" übersetzt.

Comment: @Iris dsafas Übersetzung ist korrekt.

Comment: @Iris: Mit solchen Vermutungen sollte vorsichtig sein wenn man eine Sprache nicht kennt. Wortpaare wie »wosch/weist« nennt man »falsche Freunde« weil sie zwar ähnlich klingen, aber unterschiedliche Dinge bedeuten. Und je ähnlicher sich zwei Sprachen sind, desto gemeiner können diese falschen Freunde sein. Berühmte Beispiele: englisch *handy* (praktisch) - deutsch *Handy* (Mobiltelefon), oder jiddisch *Jauch* (Suppe) - deutsch *Jauche* (flüssige tierische Exkremente)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, da hast du Recht und es tut mir leid, wenn meine Frage als Vorwurf aufgefasst wurde.

Comment: @Iris: Ich glaube nicht, dass irgend jemand deine Frage als Vorwurf aufgefasst hat. Viele haben sie als Folge eines Irrtums aufgefasst. Jedenfalls war das bei mir so der Fall.

Comment: Hintergrund von Iris' Nachfrage war natürlich, dass Schwäbisch und Schweizerdeutsch als verschiedene Formen von Alemannisch ungefähr so nah miteinander verwandt sind, wie bayrische und österreichische Dialekte. Beide teilen sich auch mit Badisch und Elsässisch eine einzige Dialekt-Wikipedia, wo übrigens in der Tat die schweizerische Variante "du witt (wettsch, wosch)" im Gegensatz zu "er weißt, isch witt" zu finden ist. [Alemannische Grammatik](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Grammatik#Verb)

Comment: Als Berner kann ich nochmal bestätigen, dass die Übersetzung korrekt ist.

Comment: Wosch sollte als 'willst' übersetzt sein; die Übersetzung ist korrekt (ich habe jahrelang im 'Bernbiet' gelebt und kenne den Dialekt gut!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wenn man nicht bereit ist Risiken einzugehen, dann tut man am besten gar nichts.

Man kann dann allerdings auch nichts gewinnen.

Comment: Oder kurz: "Wer nicht wagt, der nicht gewinnt".